# Corona runtime addEventListener to be execute inside if else condition

Tags: lua, runtime, coronasdk

How do I run this function "Runtime:addEventListener("notification", onNotification)" inside if else condition. The function is to register with GCM, but by default it keep registering everytime I open the app. What I wanted to do is, call remote db which save RegID of the device, and if it exist, dont register again with GCM. How do I do that?

```
local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
            print( "Network error!")
    else
            local json = require "json"
            local t = json.decode(event.response)
            local status = t.status
            local isReg = t.isRegistered
            print(event.response)
            if (isReg == "1") then
                native.showAlert("success",isReg,{"OK"})
            else
                native.showAlert("fail",isReg,{"OK"})
                Runtime:addEventListener("notification", onNotification)
            end

    end
end
```

### Below is the onNotification runtime function

```
-- Called when a notification event has been received.
local function onNotification(event)
print("onNotification berjalan")

    if event.type == "remoteRegistration" then
        -- This device has just been registered for Google Cloud Messaging     (GCM) push notifications.
        -- Store the Registration ID that was assigned to this application     by Google.
        googleRegistrationId = event.token

        -- Display a message indicating that registration was successful.
        local message = "This app has successfully registered for Google push notifications."
        --native.showAlert("Information", message, { "OK" })
        printTable(message);

        local function submitReg( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
            print( "Network error!")
        else
            local json = require "json"
            local t = json.decode(event.response)
            print(t)        
            end
        end

        local headers = {}

        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"

        local body = "key=5b41b02152251a3c19a5c3ac88c074cf11aacb19&uid="..tostring(googleRegistrationId)

        local params = {}
        params.headers = headers
        params.body = body

        print("running submit " , body)

        network.request( "http://www.domain.com/api.php?package=com.sample.app&platform=android&action=register", "POST", submitReg, params)



        -- Print the registration event to the log.
        print("### --- Registration Event ---")
        printTable(event)

    else
        -- A push notification has just been received. Print it to the log.
        print("### --- Notification Event ---")
        printTable(event.response)
    end
 end
```

Above is my current code. The Runtime function won't execute within if else condition. How can I make it executing ?

Comment: Could you show us the error you are getting? Adding an event listener just means adding a listener that call the function "onNotification" whenever the "notification" event occurs. I assume you only want the listener when the condition is met?

Comment: here the error im getting :

`attempt to index local 'event' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 [C]: ?
in function 'onNotification'`

Comment: The error seems to be in the onNotification function, could you include the code for your "onNotification" function code?

Comment: I have edited the question and the `onNotification` is included

Comment: I am unable to spot anything wrong - could be an oversight - but my initial though is that the "local function submitReg  (event)" is causing the trouble. Since you are creating a new function like normal, but you need to remember that when you put the parameter "event" and check "event.isError" you are actually parsing the event parameter from "onNotification"

Comment: Why do you want to set up an onNotification listener inside a network.request() handler?  If you want to respond to registration events so you can register with your Push Notification sender, then you need to enable this listener in your main.lua.  Also your app's receiving a push notification has nothing to do with a network transfer. This is something that should be setup in main.lua and no where else.

Answer (score 0):

It is because by the time you run your check the network request is still in the process.

try this

```
local function networkListener( event )
 if event.phase == "ended" then 

    if ( event.isError ) then
            print( "Network error!")
    else
            local json = require "json"
            local t = json.decode(event.response)
            local status = t.status
            local isReg = t.isRegistered
            print(event.response)
            if (isReg == "1") then
                native.showAlert("success",isReg,{"OK"})
            else
                native.showAlert("fail",isReg,{"OK"})
                Runtime:addEventListener("notification", onNotification)
            end

    end
end

end
```